# I want to add all results to csv, but it only adds the first page results

Tags: javascript, html, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I am very new to Coding. Currently I am learning some web scraping tutorials.
I have some issues in my code. I want to add all results to csv, but it only adds the first page results.

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const otcsv = require('objects-to-csv');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { Console } = require('console');

const baseUrl = ['https://clutch.co/directory/mobile-application-developers?page=1','https://clutch.co/directory/mobile-application-developers?page=2'];
const getCompanies = async () => {
    for (n = 0; n < baseUrl.length; n++) {
        const html = await rp(baseUrl[n]);
        const businessMap = cheerio('h3 > a', html).map(async (i, e) => {
            const link = "https://clutch.co" + e.attribs.href;
            const innerHtml = await rp(link);
            let title = cheerio('.h2_title', innerHtml).text().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
            let rating = cheerio('#summary_section > div > div.col-md-6.summary-description > div:nth-child(2) > div.col-md-9 > div > span', innerHtml).text();
            let name = e.children[0].data;
            //console.log(name)

            return {
                title,
                rating,
                name
            }
        }).get();
        return Promise.all(businessMap);
    }

};
  getCompanies()
  .then(result => {
    const transformed = new otcsv(result);
    return transformed.toDisk('./output.csv');
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

And one more question: Can anyone please explain this line

```
const businessMap = cheerio('h3 > a', html).map(async (i, e) => {
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are already returning the first result in your FOR-Loop in your function *getCompanies*. Once you return inside a function it is finished so the other iterations are not executed. Therefore you only get the results for the first page.

You can create a buffer array outside the FOR-Loop and add results from inside the FOR-Loop and then return all results below the FOR-Loop.

For example (without testing your code):

```
const getCompanies = async () => {
    const results = [];

    for (n = 0; n < baseUrl.length; n++) {
        const html = await rp(baseUrl[n]);
        const businessMap = cheerio('h3 > a', html).map(async (i, e) => {
            const link = "https://clutch.co" + e.attribs.href;
            const innerHtml = await rp(link);
            let title = cheerio('.h2_title', innerHtml).text().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
            let rating = cheerio('#summary_section > div > div.col-md-6.summary-description > div:nth-child(2) > div.col-md-9 > div > span', innerHtml).text();
            let name = e.children[0].data;
            //console.log(name)

            return {
                title,
                rating,
                name
            }
        }).get();

        const result = await Promise.all(businessMap);
        
        results.concat(result);
    }

    return results;
};
```

Comment: Can you please show me one example. i am very new to coding @mattigrthr

Comment: Hey @ArunkumarS, sure, I added one. Let me know if that works for you now.